# Setting Reply-to in mailgun

Tags: mailgun

I've seen the API for this which suggests adding the `Reply-To` header or `h:Reply-To` param. I don't have any experience with headers so that may be why I'm having trouble with this.

I'm trying to construct the request in postman, and I've tried putting `Reply-To` as a header key and an email as the value, and I've also tried without that header and instead with a param with the key `h:Reply-To` but when I hit "reply" to the email that gets sent, it always replies to the sender instead of my reply-to address.

Can anyone help me?

#### as header

```
POST /v3/sandboxXXXXba.mailgun.org/messages?from=messages@xxxx.com&amp; to=xxxx1@gmail.com&amp; subject=hello&amp; text=mailgun-test HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mailgun.net
Reply-To: xxxx2@gmail.com
Authorization: Basic xxxx
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxxx
```

#### as param

```
POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxXXXX.mailgun.org/messages?from=messages@domain.com&to=me@gmail.com&subject=hello&text=mailgun-test&h:Reply-To=me@gmail.com

aka:

POST /v3/sandboxXXXXX33ba.mailgun.org/messages?from=messages@mydomain.com&amp; to=myaddress@gmail.com&amp; subject=hello&amp; text=mailgun-test&amp; h:Reply-To=myaddress@gmail.com HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mailgun.net
Authorization: Basic xxxxx
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxx
Host: api.mailgun.net
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

So it should be a form-data body parameter:

```
POST /v3/skedda.co/messages HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mailgun.net
Authorization: Basic YX...
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ...
Host: api.mailgun.net
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Length: 781
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache


Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"

postmaster@...com
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--,
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

a....com
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--,
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

link test
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--,
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="html"

<h1>Hello world</h1>
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--,
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="h:Reply-To"

notifications@...com
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

or in Postman itself

[image]

Comment: I believe that's what I tried in my second example ("as param")

Comment: @JonathanTuzman I guess it's not 100% true.You're trying to pass it as a _query string_ param, but what they expect is a body parameter. I've tried it your way and it really doesn't apply the reply-to if I put it in the query string. But if you use postman you should probably get the same picture as me, don't you?

Comment: Oh! I didn't know about body parameters! Thanks.